# Can I say I landed at Boston?

Tags: grammaticality, business-language

I know the plane lands in Boston but can I say I landed in Boston ?

Comment: You land **at** the airport **in** Boston. The identity of the airport is usually irrelevant, and it's usual to simply refer to the city you're going to. But you can use either preposition.

Answer (score 1):

Both planes and persons can land at Boston, which implies the airport of that city.